# Подсчет цифр в массиве , программа не выполняет свою функцию

Tags: java

Программа должна подсчитывать, количество каждой цифры в массиве, (от 1 до 9), но в 
итоге программа ничего не делает. Прошу указать ошибки.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int [] x  = new int[10000];
  int [] c  = new int[9];
    for (int j=0;j < x.length; j++ ){
     x[j]= scan.nextInt();
      switch(x[j]){
       case 1:
        c[0]++;
          break;
       case 2:
        c[1]++;
          break;
       case 3:
        c[2]++;
          break;
       case 4: 
        c[3]++;
          break;
       case 5:
        c[4]++;
          break;
       case 6: 
        c[5]++;
          break;
       case 7: 
        c[6]++;
          break;
       case 8:
        c[7]++;
          break;
       case 9:
        c[8]++;
          break;
       }
  }
for (int v : c ) 
System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Извиняюсь перед теми , кто отвечал на данный вопрос, я не полностью сделал задание, при встречи 0, for должен заканчиваться,

Вот собственно и решение

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args){
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
int[] x = new int[100000]; 
int[] c = new int[9]; 
boolean stop = false; 

for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) { 
if (stop) break; 

x[j] = scan.nextInt(); 

switch (x[j]) { 
case 1: 
c[0]++; 
break; 
case 2: 
c[1]++; 
break; 
case 3: 
c[2]++; 
break; 
case 4: 
c[3]++; 
break; 
case 5: 
c[4]++; 
break; 
case 6: 
c[5]++; 
break; 
case 7: 
c[6]++; 
break; 

case 8: 
c[7]++; 
break; 

case 9: 
c[8]++; 
break; 
case 0: 
stop = true; 
break; 
} 
} 
for (int v : c) 

System.out.println(v);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Почему не делает? [Делает](https://ideone.com/tp648J)

В связи со вновь открывшимися обстоятельствами вносим обработку нуля.
Изменения в [коде](https://ideone.com/YL6va8):
Массив не используется, значит, он не нужен, используем простую переменную.
Индексы не нужны, цикл по семантике более всего подходит `do..while`.
Весь этот switch  лучше заменить на `c[x - 1]++;`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  int [] c  = new int[9];
  do {
      int x= scan.nextInt();
      if (x == 0)
           break;
      c[x-1]++;
   }  while (true);

  for (int v: c) 
     System.out.println(v);
  }
}
```

Кроме того, стоит предусмотреть обработку неверного ввода (например, что будет при наличии чисел больше 9?)

Comment: Странно, в других онлайн компиляторах он не работает upd. с этими цифрами не работает 1 1 4 1 5 8 6 3 5 1 0

Comment: Ну так ноль же. Я подумал, что ноль специально исключён.  По ссылке модифицированный вариант

Comment: я допустил тотальную ошибку, сейчас все исправлю, извините